# Do multiple QWebEngineViews use the same web page cache profile

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside6

I have multiple instances of `QWebEngineView`, each of which loads the same URL (e.g. "https://*****.com/login),

```
widget = Qwidget()
lay= QHBoxLayout()
initialUrl = "https://******.com/login/"
for i in range(3):
    frame = QFrame()
    web_lay = QVBoxlayout()
    webView = QWebEngineView()
    webView.load(QUrl(initialUrl))

    reload_button = QPushButton(QIcon(":/icons/images/icons/cil-loop"), "", self)
    reload_button.setToolTip("reload")
    reload_button.clicked.connect(lambda: webView.reload()) 
   # This is a wrong way of writing, so each button cannot be corresponding to WebView.
   # I write this just to express that I have a corresponding button for each

    web_lay.addwidget(webView)
    web_lay.addWidget(reload_button)
    Frame.setLayout(web_lay)
    
    lay.addwidget(frame)
```

Once I login to the corresponding website account in a `QWebEngineView`, the page displayed will also be refreshed after other pages are refreshed，refresh(clicked reload button) the interface in the unlogin `QWebEngineView`, and the refreshed interface will be the logged interface.

What I excepted is that each `QWebEngineView` can log in to a different account

Anyone else faced such issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that each `QWebEngineView` uses the same default `QWebEngineProfile` unless specified otherwise.  What you need to do is create a unique `QWebEngineProfile` for each `QWebEngineView` and create a `QWebEnginePage` that uses that profile and assign it to the `QWebEngineView`...

For example:

```py
from PySide6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEngineProfile, QWebEnginePage

...
for i in range(3):
    storage = "unique/storage/location" + str(i) # <- unique for each iteration
    frame = QFrame()
    web_lay = QVBoxlayout()
    webView = QWebEngineView()
    profile = QWebEngineProfile(storage, webview)
    page = QWebEnginePage(profile, webview)
    webview.setPage(page)
    webView.load(QUrl(initialUrl))
    ...

...
```

Once you have assigned the page to the view each view will run independently of the other.  The will each have a separate cache, separate histories, separate cookies, separate settings etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem has been solved

Comment: @whk  If my answer helped please mark the question as complete