# Python PyQt6 QWebEngineView Multiple Downloads

Tags: python, download, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

I'm having trouble downloading multiple files through a QWebEngineView in PyQt6 on Python. I've tried a few different ways (opening the window twice, creating multiple views, etc.) but I can only ever get a maximum of one of the files downloaded.

Here is one example of my download window:

```
class DownloadFileWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, fileNames: list, urls: list, saveFolder: str):

        super().__init__()

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)

        for i in range(len(fileNames)):

            view = QWebEngineView()

            view.page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(partial(self.onDownloadRequested, fileNames[i], saveFolder))

            view.load(QUrl(urls[i]))

            hbox.addWidget(view)

    def onDownloadRequested(self, fileName: str, saveFolder: str, download: QWebEngineDownloadRequest):

        download.setDownloadDirectory(saveFolder)
        download.setDownloadFileName(fileName)
        download.accept()
```

In the above example, only the first file in the list is downloaded, and I get the below messages in the console (not errors, the execution doesn't stop):

> Setting the download directory is not allowed after the download has been accepted.
> Setting the download file name is not allowed after the download has been accepted.

So it looks like no matter what I try, it keeps trying to use the same download variable, even though I instantiate it for each file (at least I think I do).

I've tried:

- opening the download window once for each URL
- creating multiple views, one for each URL
- waiting for each download to finish before starting the next one

but I get the same or similar problems where only the first file is downloaded.

I would expect that at least one of these methods allows me to download all of the files that I want, but no dice.

Comment: By default, QWebEnginePages share a common profile, and you're always using that, so you're practically connecting the same signal **more than once** to the same function, with the same argument, which is the cause of the error you're seeing: if you have 3 items in that list, *every* download request will call `onDownloadRequested` *three times*, with the *same* download. Besides, your code is not reproducible, because `url` is not defined, there's only a `urls` variable but it's never used. Please provide a valid [mre] (but consider the point above).

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm on my work computer and I'm not allowed to paste into StackOverflow so I had to rewrite the whole thing into the post. I changed it to urls[i].

How would I get around that limitation? I tried calling creating the window multiple times (once for each url) and multiple applications (one for each url). Always the same result.

Comment: The first question you should answer is: do you *actually* need to use QWebEngineView? For instance, because the url uses some advanced cookie/js management to finally start the download? Because, if it's not, there's absolutely no point in using the QtWebEngine framework, just use QNetworkAccessManager.

Comment: As far as I know, yes, I need to use QWebEngineView. I looked into QNetworkAccessManager and tried a few different examples I could find but none of them worked. I'm trying to download files from SharePoint Online, and my company has it set up that it automatically logs us in. Depending on the example I tried, I either get SSL errors, or login errors (and I can't provide credentials because it's automatic; there are no fields to populate to log in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @musicamante, I knew what I had to search for and found a solution on another SO post: [Do multiple QWebEngineViews use the same web page cache profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73105117/do-multiple-qwebengineviews-use-the-same-web-page-cache-profile)

As @musicamante said, the issue is that each `QWebEngineView` uses the same default `QWebEngineProfile` unless specified otherwise. A unique `QWebEngineProfile` for each `QWebEngineView` must be created along with a `QWebEnginePage` that uses that profile, then assign those to the `QWebEngineView`.

Copied example from the other SO answer:

```
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEngineProfile, QWebEnginePage

...
for i in range(3):
    storage = "unique/storage/location" + str(i)  # <- unique for each iteration
    webview = QWebEngineView()
    profile = QWebEngineProfile(storage, webview)
    page = QWebEnginePage(profile, webview)
    webview.setPage(page)
    webview.load(QUrl(url))
    ...

...
```

Comment: Note that you should always ensure that the storage path gets cleared when the download is finished, and you should also probably check on startup if previously created profiles exist, so that you could eventually delete them: if the program is run a lot of times, with lots of urls, you may end up with *a lot* of unnecessarily used disk space. Also, I'm not familiar with SharePoint, but if there's no requirement for user actions in order to finally download the file, there's no point in using a view: you can do the same by just using a QWebEnginePage and then improve resource usage.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I made sure to delete the profiles when the downloads are done.